# Remove null values while keeping groups

Tags: sql

I have a table thats being created through a number of joins, something similar to whats below

```
Episode|Case|Description|code|
------------------------------
1      |b22 |something..| a23|
1      |a12 |null       |null|
2      |gh11|something..| a23|
3      |b877|something..|7thb|
```

Essentially, the episode is unique but each episode may or may not have multiple cases and then for each case there will be among other things, a description and a code - These may be null for some cases of an episode.

What i need to be able to do is remove the null rows, but not remove the episodes. So if an episode appears once and it has null values i need to keep it, where if it appears 5 times and has null values for 3 rows, i want to get rid of the 3 null rows.

Ive been trying for awhile but im just not sure how to achieve what im trying to achive.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where coalesce(t.description, t.code) is not null
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where episode = t.episode and coalesce(description, code) is not null
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fvxhxm6USLXJ6KoawLLHe6/0).
Results:

```
| Episode | Case | Description | code |
| ------- | ---- | ----------- | ---- |
| 1       | b22  | something.. | a23  |
| 2       | gh11 | something.. | a23  |
| 3       | b877 | something.. | 7thb |
```

Answer (score 0):

As a `select` you would do:

```
select e.*
from episodes e
where case is not null or
      not exists (select 1 from episodes e2 where e2.episode = e.episode and e2.case is not null);
```

Note that `case` is a very poor name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.

If you wanted to actually delete the rows, you would use `delete`:

```
delete from episodes
    where episodes.case is null and
          exists (select 1
                  from episodes e2 
                  where e2.episode = episodes.episode and e2.case is not null
                 );
```